# Python 3.4 IDLE not working properly in MacOSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard, crashes when the editor is started

Tags: python, crash, osx-snow-leopard, python-idle

I am new to Python and I have installed the 64-bit version 3.4.1 using the .dmg installer from the Python website, and when I start IDLE and try to create a new file, IDLE crashes and quits. Same thing happens when I try to load a Python file using the "File > Open" option.

I am running Mac OSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard on an iMac Intel Core i3 21.5in, and the Python version is 3.4.1.

IDLE itself seems to work, it's only when I try to create a new file or load a file that it quits.

Just to add, the create new file opens a small blank window with no header, which then causes both windows to become unresponsive. I would include a screenshot but I don't have enough rep :(

EDIT: I just installed an older version of Python (3.3.5), and have encountered the same issue, which makes me think that maybe it's something to do with my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

Solved by installing Python version 3.1.0, in which the Python runtime and the IDLE editor both seem to work with no problems (so far).

I would add that:

- I am only writing **really** **simple** scripts based on a tutorial and
- The editor only works when started by **clicking on File > New Window**

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this problem, but I suspect a tkinter problem.  If you have not, please read and follow this [tcl/tk on Mac](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk) advice.   If you continue having problems, I strongly recommend you post to the python-list mailing list, where some python-mac users hang out, including one of the people who maintain python and idle on osx.  You can easily do so at news.gmane.org in their gmane.comp.python.general newsgroup mirror of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Terry, I have not read that so I will do now. Will 1up this when I have enough rep.